# Schedule a Job every minute on the exact minute during specific times using Python Schedule Library?

Tags: python, schedule

I am using the Python Schedule Library and I have been using the following line of code to schedule a job to run every minute, on the exact minute regardless what time the program is started. For instance, if the program is ran at 13:51:30, rather than starting one minute after that time which would be 13:52:30, it will start at 13:52:00.
This is the line of code used to achieve this:

```
schedule.every(1).minutes.at(":00").do(job)
```

Now, how can I get schedule to do this between specific times? For instance, if I want this schedule to occur during 10:00 till 11:00?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood the question correctly. I use this:

```
def func():
now_datetime = datetime.now()
if (now_datetime.hour >= 10) & (now_datetime.hour < 11) :
    print(now_datetime)


def main():
    while True:
        schedule.every().minute.at(':00').do(func)

        while True:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: This is great thank you. It does exactly what I need it to do, I didn't consider putting the conditional if statement inside the function. The only concern I have with this is that if I put the conditional if statement inside the function, then still every minutes outside of the hours specified the schedule will continue to run. Would such a simple script cause any issues if being run on the background of a modern computer?